# How to scrape a web site using Python, Requests and Xpath?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I try to scrape first name + last name of people on this web page (https://www.meleenumerique.com/scientist_comite)  using the code below but it doesn't work. How can I determine what's wrong with it?

This is the code I wrote

```
from lxml import html  
import csv,os,json
import requests
url="https://www.meleenumerique.com/scientist_comite"
r=requests.get(url)
t=html.fromstring(r.content)

title=t.xpath('/html/head/title/text()')
#Create the list of speaker
speaker=t.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"speaker-name")]//text()')

print(title)
print("Speakers:",speaker)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with this [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) library which should let you scrape the content from that page. This library supports xpath and has the ability to take care of dynamic content.

```
import requests_html

session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.meleenumerique.com/scientist_comite')
r.html.render(sleep=5, timeout=8)
for item in r.html.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'speaker-name')]"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: only python 3.6 is supported... I will go back to selenium...