# What is the best way to scrape data from a site with multiple links derived from the original link with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

In the example I have listed below it is a page for all the alumni relations chapters for Virginia Tech. I would like to go into each one of the alumni relations chapters and create a CSV file for each piece of information listed. I have attempted to use BeautifulSoup, but have been unsuccessful.

Any help on this topic is much appreciated thank you!

[image: Example of the data I am looking to scrape]

```
url=https://www.alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list.html


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'https://www.alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list.html'

result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: You should try it with [XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459924/how-to-scrape-a-web-site-using-python-requests-and-xpath) :-) Read also [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can crawl each link found in the chapter list page and get some info from the subpages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

links = []
for a in soup.select(".general-body li > a"):
    links.append(a["href"])

for u in links:
    print(f"Opening {u}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")

    # get some info here:
    contact = soup.select_one(".general-body strong:-soup-contains(Contact)")
    if contact:
        c = contact.next_element.next_element
        c = c.text.strip()

        print(contact.text, c)
```

Prints:

```
Opening https://alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list/alleghany_highlands.html
Contact: Kathleen All          
Opening https://alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list/augusta.html                                    
Contact:  augustacountyhokies@gmail.com                                                                  
Opening https://alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list/central_virginia.html       
Contact:  Sammy Paris                                                                                                                                                                                              
Opening https://alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list/charlottesville.html 
Contact: Martin Harar                                                                                    
Opening https://alumni.vt.edu/chapters/chapter_list/commonwealth.html
Contact:  Volunteers Needed             

...
```